# Error code 80c6 occurs when tia portal connects to mosquitto broker

Tags: mosquitto, tia-portal

I am trying to connect with mosquitto Broker through Tia Portal. But I got error code 16#80C6. I checked the relevant information, and the error message is "The connection partner cannot be reach (network error)". But still, I don't know how to fix this. Can someone help me?
By the way. The ip address of my computer is 192.168.0.103. The ip address of Siemens PLCSIM Virtual Ethernet Adapter is 192.168.0.10. The ip address of the plc I set is 192.168.0.20

Very thanksful if you can help me.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you read the output of mosquitto?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278648/mosquitto-starting-in-local-only-mode/

Comment: very thanksful to you，hardillb.Your answer solves part of my problem, and the other part is that my own firewall didn't add the corresponding port. The problem has now been solved, thank you very much. If I encounter problems after that, please help me. Thank you