# messaging with mqtt in same network between two different pc

Tags: mqtt, iot

How do I publish and subscribe through MQTT in two PC connected in the same network through LAN with Publisher and Subscriber in different PC.
I have my PC connected to same network interface (ethernet) with Ubuntu as is operating system.

To test, on subscribing pc i put the command `mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t topic_name` and on the publisher pc `mosquitto_pub -h subscriber_ip -t topic_name -m message`. This returns an error,  `connection refused` or sometimes `network is unreachable`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: For subscribing pc i put the command 'mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t topic_name'. For publisher pc 'mosquitto_pub -h subscriber_ip -t topic_name -m message, but it shows connection refused or sometimes network is unreachable...why? what can be done to fix it??

Comment: Is Mosquitto (or another broker) running on `subscriber_ip`? If so please share your `mosquitto.conf` and the log (set `log_type` to `all` - see the [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) for details). Note: when adding detail please edit the question (makes it easier to see all relevant info in one place).

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/65278769/504554

Comment: I did as follows, but now after publishing the message if I subscribe with a new device, it does not receive the message immediately instead I have to publish the message again to recieve it. Why does that happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Install mqtt broker like Mosquitto in both machine.
https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-on-ubuntu-20-04-server/#Introduction this link could help. You can enter command 'mosquitto -v' to check if it is installed.

Now for subscribing pc hit command 'mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t topic_name'. For publisher pc 'mosquitto_pub -h subscriber_ip -t topic_name -m message. If the message is displayed on subscribing pc, the mqtt is working fine. Now, you can explore security/wildcard and other features as well.

Comment: "mqtt broker like Mosquitto in both machine" - why both machines? If you are suggesting this to gain access to the command line tools then the `mosquitto-clients` package is probably a better choice. Also note that the default mosquitto configuration only accepts local connections (so some additional configuration is needed - i.e.  `listener`).