# Connection issues in TLS/SSL based publisher-subscriber implementation using paho-mqtt in python for Mosquitto

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

I need to do a comparison between MQTT and MQTTS in python using [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) (An MQTT message broker).
I already have a working MQTT based publisher-subscriber implementation for Mosquitto. I tried making the required changes (for TLS/SSL) in Mosquitto configuration and pub-sub scripts but was unable to get the whole implementation working correctly.
Please help me in debugging my TLS/SSL based pub-sub implementation at the end.

I setup [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/)(An MQTT message broker) on my local Ubuntu machine via [snap](https://mosquitto.org/download/).

I was able to implement basic publisher-subscriber using [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt) in python without TLS/SSL.

After doing required TLS/SSL confifuration, I was able to get mosquitto running on port 8883 (Default port for TLS/SSL). I also made required changes in pub-sub scripts for TLS/SSL.

After running publisher script multiple times I observed that first n messages out of 10 (generally saw 1<=n<=5) get successfully published after which the connection gets lost and rest of the messages fail to publish.

When running subsciber script, I was getting `Connection refused - not authorised` according to [docs](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#on_connect) (since I was getting rc=5 in `on_connect(...)`)

Publisher script:

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

messaging_protocol = 'MQTTS'
ca_file = '/home/tp/mosquitto_poc/steves-internet/ca.crt'
broker_address = 'localhost'
topic = 'topic1'

client = mqtt.Client('publisher-client')

if messaging_protocol == 'MQTTS':
    port = 8883
    client.tls_set(ca_file)
else:
    # When messaging_protocol will be 'MQTT'
    port = 1883

client.connect(broker_address, port)

for i in range(10):
    payload = f'Message no. {i+1}'
    print(f'Attempting to publish message: `{payload}`')
    mqtt_msg_info = client.publish(topic, payload)
    try:
        is_published = mqtt_msg_info.is_published()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f'Error occured: `{str(e)}`. Rc value: {mqtt_msg_info.rc}.', end='\n\n')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'Error occured: `{str(e)}`. Rc value: {mqtt_msg_info.rc}. Error string: `{mqtt.error_string(mqtt_msg_info.rc)}`', end='\n\n')
    else:
        print(f'Message published: {is_published}. Rc value: {mqtt_msg_info.rc}. Error string: `{mqtt.error_string(mqtt_msg_info.rc)}`', end='\n\n')
    finally:
        time.sleep(0.005)
```

Sample Output on Publisher script run:

```
Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 1`
Message published: True. Rc value: 0. Error string: `No error.`

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 2`
Message published: True. Rc value: 0. Error string: `No error.`

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 3`
Message published: True. Rc value: 0. Error string: `No error.`

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 4`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The connection was lost.`. Rc value: 7.

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 5`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`. Rc value: 4.

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 6`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`. Rc value: 4.

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 7`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`. Rc value: 4.

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 8`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`. Rc value: 4.

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 9`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`. Rc value: 4.

Attempting to publish message: `Message no. 10`
Error occured: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`. Rc value: 4.
```

Subscriber script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

messaging_protocol = 'MQTTS'
ca_file = '/home/tp/mosquitto_poc/steves-internet/ca.crt'
broker_address = 'localhost'
topic = 'topic1'


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print(f'Connected with result code {str(rc)}')
    result, _ = client.subscribe(topic)
    print(f'Attempting to subscribe topic: `{topic}`. Result value: {result}. Error string: `{mqtt.error_string(result)}`')


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(f'Received message: `{msg.payload}` on topic: {msg.topic}')


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print(f'Client disconnected. Rc value: {rc}. Error string: `{mqtt.error_string(rc)}`', end='\n\n')


client = mqtt.Client('subscriber-client')

if messaging_protocol == 'MQTTS':
    port = 8883
    client.tls_set(ca_file)
else:
    # When messaging_protocol will be 'MQTT'
    port = 1883

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

client.connect(broker_address, port)

client.loop_forever()
```

Output on Subscriber script run:

```
Connected with result code 5
Attempting to subscribe topic: `topic1`. Result value: 0. Error string: `No error.`
Client disconnected. Rc value: 5. Error string: `The connection was refused.`

Connected with result code 5
Attempting to subscribe topic: `topic1`. Result value: 0. Error string: `No error.`
Client disconnected. Rc value: 5. Error string: `The connection was refused.`

Connected with result code 5
Attempting to subscribe topic: `topic1`. Result value: 0. Error string: `No error.`
Client disconnected. Rc value: 5. Error string: `The connection was refused.`

Connected with result code 5
Attempting to subscribe topic: `topic1`. Result value: 0. Error string: `No error.`
Client disconnected. Rc value: 5. Error string: `The connection was refused.`

Connected with result code 5
Attempting to subscribe topic: `topic1`. Result value: 0. Error string: `No error.`
Client disconnected. Rc value: 5. Error string: `The connection was refused.`
```

Please help me in debugging this TLS/SSL based pub-sub implementation. Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Comment: Remove the Snap package, and install the proper deb (because it's way too much work to debug the snap sandbox file access restrictions when it comes to the certificates.), then show us how you have edited the `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` file and the mosquitto log files

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278648/mosquitto-starting-in-local-only-mode

Comment: Thanks @hardillb, I was able to get it working with TLS/SSL through your suggestions & some other changes. I will add more details in the answer.