# Simple MQTT subscriber using Python paho-mqtt works on LInux, but fails on Windows 11

Tags: python, linux, windows, mqtt

This Python 3.11 script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def onMQTT(client, userdata, message):
  print(message.payload)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  topic = 'top'
  client = mqtt.Client()
  client.connect('localhost', 1883)
  client.message_callback_add(topic, onMQTT)
  (result, mid) = client.subscribe(topic, qos=2)

  if result == mqtt.MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS:
    print(f'Subscribed to: {topic}.')

  client.loop_forever()
```

works as expected on Linux. On Windows 11, it prints `Subscribed to: top.`, but fails to receive topics, while `mosquitto_sub -t 'top'` command receives `top` topics with no problem. Is there anything different I have to do, in order to make this script work on Windows 11?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (Windows 11 + Mosquitto - output `b'test` when I ran `mosquitto_pub.exe' -t top -m test`). I'd suggest checking the broker logs and, perhaps [enable logging](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_logger.py) in your app.

Comment: Assuming the broker is on the Linux machine, did you remember to change the broker hostname from `localhost` when on Windows? Also did you enable the broker to allow access from remote hosts (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278648/mosquitto-starting-in-local-only-mode)?

Comment: @hardillb *change the broker hostname from localhost when on Windows* Change to what name? I'm testing local access only.

Comment: @Brits I did both and the logs are very sparse, not adding anything new. The script is pinging the broker, which responds. Log doesn't show the topic being received by the script.

Comment: @hardillb I added *listener 1883
allow_anonymous true* to *mosquitto.conf*, which didn't change the behavior.

Comment: So you can't see the subscribe in the logs? (Maybe easier to share the log). You may want to move the `subscribe` to an `on_connect` callback).

Comment: @Brits Verbose log was the key to this puzzle. I noticed the unintended topic name. Details in my answer. Thank you for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the script. The problem lies in testing method. This Linux command:

```
mosquitto_pub -t 'top' -m 'hello'
```

has different meaning on Windows. It publishes to `'top'` instead of `top`. The Windows (and Linux) equivalent is:

```
mosquitto_pub -t top -m hello
```